# How do you get stroke = 0 for a plot with geom_point when exporting to a PDF?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, knitr, cairo

I am trying to export a ggplot object as a PDF using cairo_pdf, mainly because I want to embed some unique fonts. I want to have `geom_point(stroke = 0)`, which removes the outline when alpha < 1.

However, when I set `stroke = 0`, I can generate a nice plot when exporting to a png, but the points become missing when exporting to a PDF.

Any idea how I can export such a plot with stroke = 0 with cairo_pdf?

Thanks!

```r
p1 <- mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(factor(cyl), hp)) + 
  geom_point(stroke = 0, size = 3, alpha = 1)
# missing points
ggsave(p1, filename = 'test.pdf', device = cairo_pdf, scale = 1, width = 3.5, height = 2,  units = "in")
# can see the point
ggsave(p1, filename = 'test.png', scale = 1, width = 3.5, height = 2,  units = "in")
```

Comment: One way of resolving it is to use `shape = 16`, which doesn't have a boundary around the point. But https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1757 suggests that `shape = 19` was chosen because of a rendering issue in some devices. Not sure if this is a complete fix...